# Can't figure out a subsituite for IE in this case

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, arrow-functions

I'm trying to get this simple function working in IE11. IE doesn't accept arrow functions and I can't figure out a good substitute that works.

This is the original code

```
var referenced_content = dsp.data.filter( x => x.tid != '');
```

I tried to do this instead and it still doesn't work.

```
var referenced_content = dsp.data.filter(function (x) { return x.tid != '');
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Your substitute should work.

Comment: "It still doesn't work" Is there an error in your console? Does it just not return what you expect? Please provide us with more information.

Comment: I think it's working it was caching the old error and now it just freezes when loading which might be from something else. I'll see if I can find a direct error.